# Extract all possible polygons from set of different types of geometrical elements in WinForms GDI - Extracted polygons will be used to fill color

Tags: winforms, graphics, polygon, gdi+, gdi

I have an input, a set of different types of 2D geometrical elements with all its attributes (arcs, circles, lines, polylines, rectangles, polygons..). These elements can be connected end to end, overlapping, intersecting.

I want to extract all possible polygons formed from this set of elements, including the outermost polygons which can be a superset of inner polygons.
(I need to integrate this in a C# .Net application, where I will extract all polygons and be able to give Color-Fill to any of those polygons)

Image available here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPrYm.png

I need to extract all the inner (green) and outer(red) polygons.

I would like to know if there is an existing implementation available for this. Or if any combination of existing solutions would provide a required output.

If there are no solutions available, how could I develop a solution?

Comment: Well, you *could* build a GraphicsPath for each *element* you have (which you didn't define), then combine Regions built from the GraphicsPaths using a wise combination of Region.Intersect() / Combine() to get the Regions generated by the intersections of the Paths, use `Graphics.FillRegion()` to color the generated intersection Regions. Handle the `RegionData` of the Region that is the combination of all Paths, to define the complex Region that is the outline (or combine all Paths in one GraphicsPath and use that to define the complex outline Region).

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in WinForms with GDI+? How much time do you have?

Comment: @Jimi, thank you for you immediate solution, I have tried this method(union of all Regions(created from GraphicsPath)), it works fine with closed objects, but doesn't work with open objects like lines, arcs (for example: consider four lines forming hash(#), union of these four lines returns area formed by end points of lines, instead it should be only inner area formed by intersections of four lines)

Comment: @Jimi, Yes, this is a C# WinForms application, where in user will be allowed to draw any 2D graphical elements, then create a fill for outer boundary formed from all selected elements.

Comment: @Jimi , If not WinForms with GDI library, if you direct me to any existing algorithm to achieve this(considering the input would be GraphicsPath of all elements), it would be really great. I will study that and make required modifications to achieve the end result. Thanks in advance.